# JSF2 Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id with outcome 'Logout'

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am using Below code for LOGOUT

```
public String logout() throws ServletException {
        cleanSession();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .invalidateSession();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .invalidateSession();


            return "Logout";

    }
```

**Logout.xhtml** page inside **login** folder but i am end up with

> Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id
>   '/core/dashboard.xhtml' for action '#{loginBean.logout}' with outcome
>   'Logout'

I tried maximum solution provide in **Stackoverflow** but not able to get solution..I tried below code as well

```
public String logout() throws ServletException {
        cleanSession();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .invalidateSession();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .invalidateSession();

        try {
            String action = request.getContextPath()
                    + "/login/Logout.xhtml";
            return action;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Exception in forwarding at Logout", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But same issue ..Can anyone tell me what the issue?

I made slight change and added this

```
<p:commandLink ajax="false" rendered="#{loginBean.loginStatus}"
                    value="Logout" actionListener="#{loginBean.logout}" action="Logout">

                </p:commandLink>
```

it was previously like this

```
<p:commandLink ajax="false" rendered="#{loginBean.loginStatus}"
                    value="Logout" action="#{loginBean.logout}"
                     >
                </p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to navigate from **/core/** to **/login/** which is another directory.

JSF implicit navigation allows you to navigate to a page in same folder or any parent folder.

Please use faces-config.xml navigation rule for this type of scenario.

Comment: Please share your folder structure, h:commandButton tag snippet.

Comment: Same issue is coming  `Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/core/dashboard.xhtml' for action 'Logout' with outcome 'Logout'`

Comment: Added in question sectrion

Comment: Can you share your <navigation-rule> configuration from faces-config.xml ?

Comment: I am using JSF2 so No Need to write Navigation rule in faces.config.xml file

Comment: You can do this w/o faces-config.xml navigation rule.
You have to provide the absolute path of the target xhtml file in the action.

Comment: Do you mean by `../core/dashboard.xhtml`

Comment: Yes.. The two dots .. are not required.
In the action specify action="/login/Logout"